# Type Error: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples when implementing Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Numpy.  I have the following variables:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[3, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3]]).T
Dr = 2
Dl = 3
Db = 4

delta_R = arr[0, 0]
delta_L  = arr[1, 0]
delta_B = arr[2, 0]
delta_theta = (delta_L - delta_R) / (Dr + Dl)
```

I'm attempting to implement the following equation:

[image]

To do so, I've written:

```
delta_x_delta_y_arr = np.array([2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array([(delta_B / delta_theta) + Db], [(delta_R / delta_theta) + Dr])])
```

Firstly, I'm not certain whether I've expressed this equation properly using Numpy arrays.  If I have, why do I see the following traceback?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5072/2142976421.py in <module>
----> 1 delta_x_delta_y_arr = np.array([2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array([(delta_B / delta_theta) + Db], [(delta_R / delta_theta) + Dr])])

TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '9.5'
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give this Numpy newbie!

Comment: Full traceback!

Comment: I added the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NumPy array should be `np.array([[...], [...]])` rather than `np.array([...], [...])`. Try

```
delta_x_delta_y_arr = 2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array([[(delta_B / delta_theta) + Db], [(delta_R / delta_theta) + Dr]])
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `np.array` argument is too long to readily read - and write correctly.  Extracted, and edited for clarity:

```
 np.array([2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * 
          np.array([(delta_B / delta_theta) + Db],
                   [(delta_R / delta_theta) + Dr])
 ]
```

The inner `array` has 2 list arguments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72905294/901925 is right in saying that it is wrong.  Here's why:

The signature for `np.array` is:

```
array(object, dtype=None, ...)
```

So it's trying to interpret the 2nd list as a `dtype`.  A typical `compound dtype` looks like:

```
[('f0',int), ('f1',float,3)]
```

In other words, if the `dtype` is a list, it expects tuples, with 2 or 3 elements.

```
Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '9.5'
```

I haven't seen this error before, but based on what I know about making `structured arrays`, this makes sense.   In cases like this, it's a good idea to double check your arguments against the function documentation.

And avoid overly long lines.